# Unable to redirect for URL ends with #

Tags: jquery, redirect, hashtag

I have a script whose structure is like below :

```
$(location).attr('href','<?php echo $this->here; ?>'+'#qualification');
```

Though I was expecting to redirect to `myurl#qualification` it does not redirect at all. If I remove the `#qualification`, it redirects successfully to desired location. How can I redirect ( or refresh the page) to url `myurl#qualification`

Comment: What does location var contain ? You may try to alter the hash property of the `<a>` tag :/

Comment: Its a `cakephp` statement. It outputs like `base_url/my_controller/my_action`

Comment: ... like `$(location).attr('href','<?php echo $this->here; ?>')[0].hash = "#qualification";`

Comment: Ya its redirecting but the has `#qualification` is removed from the url.

Comment: May it be a server side url rewritting issue !?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the '+' :

```
$(location).attr('href','<?php echo $this->here; ?>#qualification');
```

Comment: Same result . not redirecting

Answer (score 0):

Try it without jQuery like this:

```
window.location.href = '<?php echo $this->here; ?>#qualification';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";

window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Read more about it here [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)